# Fetching with variable or without PHP

Tags: php, variables, fetch

```
$url = isset($_GET["url"]) ? $this->checkValues($_GET["url"]) : $this->jDie();
$query = $this->query("SELECT * FROM `torrents` WHERE `url` = '".$url."'");
$fetch = $this->fetch($query) or $this->rURL('/#invalid-url');
```

**Version 1:**

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="age" value="3" '.($this->contains("3", $fetch['age']) ? 'checked="checked"' : '').' class="age"/><span>3+</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="age" value="7" '.($this->contains("7", $fetch['age']) ? 'checked="checked"' : '').' class="age"/><span>7+</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="age" value="12" '.($this->contains("12", $fetch['age']) ? 'checked="checked"' : '').' class="age"/><span>12+</span></label>
```

**Version 2:**

```
$age = $fetch['age'];
```

[...]

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="age" value="3" '.($this->contains("3", $age) ? 'checked="checked"' : '').' class="age"/><span>3+</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="age" value="7" '.($this->contains("7", $age) ? 'checked="checked"' : '').' class="age"/><span>7+</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="age" value="12" '.($this->contains("12", $age) ? 'checked="checked"' : '').' class="age"/><span>12+</span></label>
```

Which way is better ?

Comment: Use the one you prefer. I personally prefer version 1.

Answer (score 2):

Up to you. If $this->fetch(query) doesn't perform any scrubbing or validation, then reaching into $_GET[] or $fetch is basically the same thing. Though reaching into $_GET[] and then using unsanitzed input is usually looked down upon because it can lead to bugs and vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

When determining which version of code to write, I would instead propose you ask yourself a series of questions.

1. Does one version provide any sort of performance benefit?
2. Is one version more readable than the other?
3. Is one version more maintainable than another version?

**For #1**, both are essentially equal. You're declaring a new variable in the second version, which will be minuscule performance hit, but not nearly as much as performing an additional query, reading a remote file, etc. This would cause me to *lean* more towards the first version, but it's not like I'm going to go back through all my code to try to remove every single instance of an unnecessary declared variable to try to improve performance.

**For #2**, again, both are essentially equal in the above code. If, on the other hand, you were doing a lot of `echo`s, you might want to opt for declaring the variable since it is *slightly* easier to read:

```
echo "You have $num $currency remaining in your $where";
```

than it is to read:

```
echo 'You have ' . $fetch['num'] . ' ' . $fetch['curency'] . ' remaining in your ' . $fetch['where'];
```

But either way, it's no biggie.

**For #3**, it doesn't really apply since this is so small and insignificant. However when using `$fetch`, someone maintaining the code has a slightly better idea of where the variable came from than if you're defining new variables all the time, so again I would *lean* towards the first one, but again, it's no biggie.